# How to traverse/fold a tree in DFS post-order

Tags: javascript, tree, functional-programming, depth-first-search, tree-traversal

Given is this tree data structure:

```
const tree = {v:"f", c:[
  {v:"b", c:[
    {v:"a", c:[]},
    {v:"d", c:[
      {v:"c", c:[]},
      {v:"e", c:[]}
    ]}
  ]},
  {v:"g", c:[
    {v:"i", c:[
      {v:"h", c:[]}
    ]}
  ]}
]};
```

So far I've managed to traverse it in BFS and DFS pre-order with a tail recursive approach:

```js
// tree fold

const foldl = concat => (valueKey, childKey) => f => acc => tree => {
  const next = (acc, [head, ...tail]) => head === undefined
   ? acc
   : next(
     f(acc) (head[valueKey]),
     concat(head[childKey]) (tail)
   );
    
  return next(acc, [tree]);
};


// auxilliary functions

const flip = f => x => y => f(y) (x);

const concat = xs => x => xs.concat(x);


// data

const tree = {v:"f", c:[
  {v:"b", c:[
    {v:"a", c:[]},
    {v:"d", c:[
      {v:"c", c:[]},
      {v:"e", c:[]}
    ]}
  ]},
  {v:"g", c:[
    {v:"i", c:[
      {v:"h", c:[]}
    ]}
  ]}
]};


// and run...

console.log("DFS pre-order", foldl(concat) ("v", "c") (concat) ([]) (tree) );
// yields ["f", "b", "a", "d", "c", "e", "g", "i", "h"]

console.log("BFS", foldl(flip(concat)) ("v", "c") (concat) ([]) (tree) );
// yields ["f", "b", "g", "a", "d", "i", "c", "e", "h"]
```

Unfortunately, I 'm not able to adapt the approach so that it can handle DFS post-order in addition - a unified approach, so to speak. The desired serialization is `["a", "c", "e", "d", "b", "h", "i", "g", "f"]`. Any help is appreciated!

**[EDIT]**

I managed to implement the post-order version - but it still not a unified solution for all three cases BFS, DFS pre-order, DFS post-order. Besides, I don't think my approach is particularly elegant. So I'm still interested in answers from people who have a better understanding of recursion than me.

```
const foldl = (valueKey, childKey) => f => acc => o => {
  const next = (acc, [head, ...tail]) => {
    // base case
    if (head === undefined) return acc;

    // branch (children)
    if (head[childKey].length > 0) {
      return next(
        acc,
        concat(head[childKey].concat({v:head[valueKey], c:[]})) (tail)
      );
    }

    // leaf (no children)
    return next(f(acc) (head[valueKey]), tail);
  };

  return next(acc, [o]);
};

foldl("v", "c") (concat) ([]) (tree);
// yields ["a", "c", "e", "d", "b", "h", "i", "g", "f"]
```

Comment: what is the rule of constructing such particular order `["a", "c", "e", "d", "b", "h", "i", "g", "f"]` ?

Comment: The depth-first search has three different orders: pre-, in- and post-order (in-order applies to binary trees only). Take a closer look into [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Comment: I tried to get your required result as a personal programming exercise (without looking at your solution). Although I'm not sure I understand all your requirements completely, I feel we sort of ended up with the same answer... Anyway, I thought I'd share my result; it might reassure you that your own solution is the right one ;) https://jsfiddle.net/73708dsm/

Comment: Really nice work. I'm curious ... can you make it work without mutating / removing the child references of nodes already traversed?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tail-recursion, you want to recurse down the tree before adding the elements:

```
function dfsPost(tree) {
   return tree.c.reduce((arr, el) => arr.concat(dfsPost(el)), []).concat(tree.v);
}

dfsPost(tree) // ["a", "c", "e", "d", "b", "h", "i", "g", "f"]
```

Less performant, but tail recursive: You can do a simple DFS, but when iterating over each element, use c.reduceRight(). Then call reverse() on the resulting array.

```
function dfsPost(tree) {
    return (function dfs(tree) {
         return [tree.v].concat(tree.c.reduceRight((arr, el) => arr.concat(dfs(el)), []))
    }(tree)).reverse();
}

dfsPost(tree) // ["a", "c", "e", "d", "b", "h", "i", "g", "f"]
```

Comment: That is a nice, succinct solution. However, I am more interested in a completely recursive solution (ideally tail recursive), in which the base case and the recursive cases are more obvious.